# For a column of strings that include (xyz) and [1] at the end of some strings, remove those characters in Python

Tags: python, regex

My df column includes strings that have additional characters in parenthesis and square brackets at the end of some strings, for those strings I'd like to delete the parenthesis, square brackets and all characters contained within.

```
2367            CROSS THREADED 
2368    ALL ABOUT ARBY [5]Res.
2369        EMILIA MEL [5]Res.
2360      DYNA REAVER (NSW)[5]
2362             PARTY MIX [5]
```

Expected outcome after clean-up

```
2367            CROSS THREADED 
2368            ALL ABOUT ARBY
2369                EMILIA MEL
2360               DYNA REAVER
2362                 PARTY MIX
```

Comment: And text following [] or () such as in the "ALL ABOUT ARBY" line that apparently has "Res." at the end (unless that is some sort of artifact)?

Comment: Yes - basically everything trailing [ or ( I'd like removed.

Comment: Try `df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'\s*(?:\[[^][]*]|\([^()]*\))\S*$', '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that help?

```
import re
before = "2369        EMILIA MEL [5]Res."
after = re.sub(r"\[.*", "", before).strip()
print(before)
print(after)
```

Which prints:

```
2369        EMILIA MEL [5]Res.
2369        EMILIA MEL
```

---

**Update**

With your comment, that you want everything after `[` or `(` removed:

```
import re
before = [
    "2369        EMILIA MEL [5]Res.",
    "2360      DYNA REAVER (NSW)[5]"
]
after = [re.sub(r"(\(|\[).*", "", b).strip() for b in before]
print(before)
print(after)
```

Which prints:

```
['2369        EMILIA MEL [5]Res.', '2360      DYNA REAVER (NSW)[5]']
['2369        EMILIA MEL', '2360      DYNA REAVER']
```

---

**Update 2**

Here is an example how to use it on a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"before": [
    "CROSS THREADED",
    "ALL ABOUT ARBY [5]Res.",
    "EMILIA MEL [5]Res.",
    "DYNA REAVER (NSW)[5]",
    "PARTY MIX [5]",
]})

df["after"] = df["before"].apply(
    lambda s: re.sub(r"(\(|\[).*", "", s).strip())
print(df)
```

Which prints:

```
                   before           after
0          CROSS THREADED  CROSS THREADED
1  ALL ABOUT ARBY [5]Res.  ALL ABOUT ARBY
2      EMILIA MEL [5]Res.      EMILIA MEL
3    DYNA REAVER (NSW)[5]     DYNA REAVER
4           PARTY MIX [5]       PARTY MIX
```

---

**Update 3**

As is being pointed out in the comments, you could also use [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) directly:

```
df["after"] = df["before"].str.replace(r"( )*(\(|\[).*", "")
```

Comment: I'll need to call it on the full column of a dataframe though, so how would you recommend running that?

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @Jayjayyy There is a `str.replace` you know. for replacing regex too.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
def trim(string):
    string = string.split('(')[0]
    string = string.split('[')[0]
    return string.strip()

df['CROSS THREADED'] = df['CROSS THREADED'].apply(lambda row: trim(string=row))
```